# How to do Intersections in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I would like to find the intersection between two lists in SystemVerilog. From Specman there's

```
var intersect: list of my_enum;
intersect = listA.all(it in listB);
```

Which I think is rather quaint. But best I've been able to come up with in SystemVerilog is:

```
typedef enum {A, B, C, D} my_enum;
my_enum listA[$] = {A, B, C};
my_enum listB[$] = {B, C, D};
my_enum intersect[$];

foreach(listA[i])
  if(listA[i] inside listB)
    intersect.push_back(listA[i]);
```

IEEE 1800-2012 does mention an intersect keyword but it does not seem to apply to this case. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`intersect` is a keyword used in SVAs. It is not advised to use any keyword as a variable name.

Check out [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 7.12 *Array manipulation methods*

I believe this is the desired equivalent function is:

```
myIntersect = listA.find with ( item inside {listB} );
```

Comment: Ah, that is true. I should've used a different name for my example. That function is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: FYI: unpacked arrays assignments should be use `'{}` (with leading single quote) instead of `{}`. `listA[$] = {A, B, C};` should be `listA[$] = '{A, B, C};` See § 7 for examples.